Line tangent to a parabola
So I was doing some AoPS Alcumus and came across this problem with a weird solution. A quadratic function $p(x)$ has lines of tangency $y=-11x-37$, $y=x-1$, and $y=9x+3$. These lines are tangent to $p$ at $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$. Determine $x_1+x_2+x_3$. Now, in the solution, it claimed to let $p(x)$ have a leading coefficient $a$ and since these lines are tangent to $p(x)$, then $p(x)-(-11x-37)=a(x-x_1)^2$,$p(x)-(x-1)=a(x-x_2)^2$, and $p(x)-(9x+3)=a(x-x_3)^2$. Now testing some other tangent lines on other parabolas this 'theorem' makes sense and I was almost able to prove it with calculus, but what is this 'theorem's' name, and how can I prove it using solely algebra? (What I think the 'theorem' is: Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ and leading coefficient $a$. If line $y=mx+b$ is tangent to $p(x)$ at point $P(x_0,p(x_0))$, then $p(x)-mx-b=a(x-x_0)^n$.

How can you tell without using calculus whether a straight line is tangent to a parabola?  But I'd be inclined to write $p(x)=a(x-b)^2+c$ and see how the arithmetic works in that form.

Please, use more descriptive titles. "Where did this formula come from? How Can I prove it?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

As to your statement of the general result I think your conjecture is wrong.  In general $p(x)-mx-b$ can be written as $a_0(x-x_0)^n+\dots+a_{n-1}(x-x_0)+a_n$. Then the curves $y=p(x)$ and $y-mx-b$ both pass through $(x_0,p(x_0))$ iff $a_n=0$, and the line is a tangent to the curve there iff $a_{n}=a_{n-1}=0$. So the criterion for tangency is that $p(x)-mx-b=(x-x_0)^2 q(x)$ for some polynomial $q$.

That you can fit a parabola y=p_2(x) tangent to three lines is true for a general configuration of three lines $a_i x+b_i y+1=0, i=1,2,3$ in the plane. In fact, you can even get a pencil of general parabolas $(a x+by)^2+cx+dy+f=0,$ where WLOG $a=1$ and $b$ is free and $c,d,f$ depend on the three points dual to the lines and on $b$, that specializes for b=0 to the unique $p_2(x)$ where the scalar factor is determined by solving for $y$ in the expression above to fit with the graph as $y-p_2(x)=0,$ i.e. really by choosing $a=1$ above.

To be tangent, the line $y = l(x)$ and the parabola $y = p(x)$ must intersect at that point, so we have $p(x_i) = l(x_i) \implies p(x_i) - l(x_i) = 0$, i.e. $x = x_i$ is a root of the parabola $p(x) - l(x)$, and so $p(x) - l(x) = a(x - x_i)(x - x_j)$ for some $x_j$.
However, because they are tangent to each other, they cannot have a second point of intersection (proving this purely algebraically is a bit messy but feel free to give it a shot). Because of that, $x_j$ cannot be a distinct value from $x_i$, otherwise it would provide a second solution to $p(x) - l(x) = 0$. Hence $p(x) - l(x)$ must in fact have a double root at $x = x_i$, meaning it is of the form $a(x - x_i)^2$.
One way to prove it via calculus would be via the repeated roots theorem. Having $p(x_i) = l(x_i)$ and $p'(x_i) = l'(x_i)$ means that $x_i$ is a double root of $p(x) - l(x)$.

It was a rather simple insight that I didn't see. Thanks for that.
